# "God of small things" sentence again

Tags: sentence-structure

Just a little simplified version

> Cheap soft-porn magazines were clipped with clothes pegs to ropes that hung from the ceiling.

This part "clothes pegs to ropes" bugs me.i get the idea that author wants to convey or do I? Clothes were on the pegs which were in turn attached to the ropes. TIA

Comment: How does the sentence in the body of your question have anything to do with the title of your question?

Comment: It's from the book whose title is in the title of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is more straightforward.  The verb "to clip" (meaning "to attach with some kind of *clip*") is modified with two adverbial phrases:

> ... with clothes pegs (*how* the magazines are attached)
>
> ... to ropes that hung from the ceiling (*where* the magazines are attached)

In the future, note which is the most likely verb modified by the phrases, and these sentences should make more sense.

Comment: Why is it clothes pegs instead of cloth pegs.like we say fabric softener not fabrics softener.

Comment: I know cloth pegs will make it seem like pegs were made of cloth.but still

Comment: @ManishKumarBalayan  ["clothes pegs"](https://i.imgur.com/fpt5Y3z.png) are wooden devices used to hold up *clothes*.  "Cloth pegs" would be pegs made from cloth.  But to some extent you shouldn't assume all English compound nouns will make sense.    For example, why is it a "strawberry" when it neither is made from straw nor grows from straw? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: In English, the plural of "cloth" is "cloths".  The word "clothes" is *not* the plural of "cloth" - it is a different word that means "apparel, usually made from cloth."  So it shouldn't be a surprise that "cloth peg" and "clothes peg" mean different things.

Answer (score 4):

Correct punctuation will make it clearer. The magazines were clipped, with clothes pegs, to ropes.

This is a clothes peg

[image]

Comment: To be fair, there is nothing wrong with the punctuation of the sentence as written.  It's just easier to understand when you add the commas.